# Prefill an HTML input with Google Apps Script variable

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am making a form on a sidebar in Google Apps Script, and I would like to autofill the "mail" input with the user's email.

I know that this variable get's the user email

`var email = Session.getEffectiveUser (). getEmail ();`

But I don't know how to pass the value obtained from that variable (the user's email) to the input on the form (inputmail2).

HTML form code:

```
<form action="">
    <div>
      <label for="inputmail2">Mail</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputmail2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="inputproblem">Your Problem</label>
      <textarea id="" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

From already thank you very much!

Comment: Use something like this:

`let inputTag = getElementsByTagName("input");
inputTag.setAttribute("value", email);`


You need to specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Templated HTML for this.  With scriptlets you can pass the variable to the HTML as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets).

To do this you would need to put this into you `.gs` code:

```js
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('filename');
html.email = email;
var output = html.evaluate();
ui.showSidebar(output);
```

Then for your form you need to insert the scriptlet `<?= email ?>` as the value:

```html
<form action="">
    <div>
      <label for="inputmail2">Mail</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputmail2" value="<?= email ?>">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="inputproblem">Your Problem</label>
      <textarea id="" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your concise answer. I've been looking for this and have found a lot of convoluted answers. 
BTW, is there a way to pre-fill an <input type="date">? So far I've had no success (perhaps I have to set it to a particular locale...?? Thanks again!

Comment: @yago for the date, you will need to put it in format `YYYY-MM-DD` for it to work.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I had to play around a bit with toISOString() method and was having some problems with weird day-light adjustment but at the end I've come up with a helper function to format dates like that and it works like a charm :)